# Why doesn't the new command work?

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\newcommand*{\QEDA}{\null\nobreak\hfill\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}

\begin{document}

test \QEDA

\end{document}
```

The error says "undefined control sequence".

Comment: Because `\blacksquare` is not defined by default? Try loading a package that defines it, e.g., `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: @frabjous Got it, thanks!

Comment: The error partially says "undefined control sequence".  The next line says "<argument> \blacksquare", and a bit later "The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was due to a misunderstanding of how to read an error message, explained and accepted in the comments.

Comment: Would be better if we have some canonicals, but it's really hard to find things around on the site. (even [Often referenced questions - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) doesn't help.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I am using Overleaf, and the error message indicates "QEDA" rather than "blacksquare".

Comment: @Ypbor -- What error report were you looking at?  You need to look at the error report from your LaTeX job, not the summary provided at the Overleaf level.  The full error message consists of more than one line, as explained in the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the undefined control sequence is `\blacksquare` because it is at the end of the line in the error message. You can define it using `\vrule` primitive:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\def\QEDA {\null\nobreak\hfill\blacksquare}
\def\blacksquare {\vrule height.7em width.7em\relax}

\begin{document}

test \QEDA

\end{document}
```

Note that if you are using TeX primitives and basic plain TeX macros (`\vrule`, `\hfill`, `\null`, `\nobreak` here) then you need not any more LaTeX package. Second note: you there is no `\ensuremath` because `\vrule` works in horizontal mode (and in math mode too).